# Linq to XML to create 1 record per specific element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Here is an XML Element "inspection" with child Elements "driver", "vehicle" and "violation", for which I need the Attribute values.
I need to create one record for each inspection that also contains the other element's attribute values.

```
<inspection inspection_date="2012-07-08" report_state="IL" report_number="ILP4E1014879" level="1" time_weight="1">   
<driver first_name="MELVIN" last_name="DANIELS" date_of_birth="1976-12-20" license_state="IL" License_number="D8505003"></driver>
<vehicle vehicle_id_number="1HSCNAPR74C501842" unit_type="Truck Tractor" license_state="IL" license_number="1234567"></vehicle>
<violations>
<violation code="122.4B2C" description="Lights" oos="N" basic="Vehicle Maint." severity_weight="4"></violation>
</violations>
</inspection>
```

Here is a snippet:

```
                dotinspections = from el in inspectionList
                                 select el;

                foreach (var el in dotinspections)
                {
                    if (el.Attribute("inspection_date") != null && el.Attribute("inspection_date").Value != null)
                    { insDate = Convert.ToDateTime(el.Attribute("inspection_date").Value); }

                    state = el.Attribute("report_state") != null && (string)el.Attribute("report_state").Value != null ? el.Attribute("report_state").Value.Replace("'", "''") : null;

                    insNumber = el.Attribute("report_number") != null && el.Attribute("report_number").Value != null ? el.Attribute("report_number").Value.Replace("'", "''") : null;

                    if (el.Attribute("level") != null && el.Attribute("level").Value != null)
                    { insLevel = Convert.ToInt32(el.Attribute("level").Value); }
```

These are in an IEnumerable "dotinspections".  I have tried just about every method using .Elements, .Descendants, .Attributes etc.., but can only get an inspection record, then a driver record, then vehicle, etc.., not one record for each full inspection.

How can I get one record per inspection?

Comment: what does dotinspections contain?

Comment: dotinspections is an IEnumerable<XElement> collection of inspections - each one is just as the sample I posted above.

Comment: it would seem that el in dotinspections contains what you are looking for.  But I may be missing something from your question.

Comment: Thanks webdad3.  Just you mentioning missing something did the trick.  When I checked the rest of my Element variables, I was not drilling into the elements. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned - thanks webdad3.
I didn't post all my code (for brevity).  The problem was me not going deeper into the nested XElements.  I needed to add "violations" and "vehicle" and other ancestors to my attributes:

```
                    licenseNumber1 = el.Element("vehicle").Attribute("license_number") != null && el.Element("vehicle").Attribute("license_number").Value != null ? el.Element("vehicle").Attribute("license_number").Value.Replace("'", "''") : null;

                    code = el.Element("violations").Element("violation").Attribute("code") != null && el.Element("violations").Element("violation").Attribute("code").Value != null ? el.Element("violations").Element("violation").Attribute("code").Value.Replace("'", "''") : null;

                    description = el.Element("violations").Element("violation").Attribute("description") != null && el.Element("violations").Element("violation").Attribute("description").Value != null ? el.Element("violations").Element("violation").Attribute("description").Value.Replace("'", "''") : null;
```